# how to poll maximum number of recrods on each poll kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have each message size 25KB average. I am getting only 15 to 18 records on each poll.How to get more number of records on each poll ?
Below is my kafka consumer configuration

```
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServer);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "ConsumerGrp");
    properties.put("request.timeout.ms", 120000);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 7000);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 4194304); // 4MB
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);


ConsumerRecords<String, Object> crs = this.consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10000));
            System.out.println("Polled count is "+crs.count());
```